# How to find literals in source code of Smartforms and in SAPScripts (or reports, if the others can't be done)

Tags: find, abap, literals, sap-smart-forms, sapscript

I'd like to check hardcoded values in (a lot of) Smartforms and SAPScript forms.

I have found a way to read the source code of both of these, but it seems that i will have to go through a lot of parsing before I get anything reliable.

I've come across function module `GET_LITERAL` but that doesn't seem to help me much since i have to specify the offset of the value, if i got right what the function is doing in the first place.

I also found `RS_LITERAL_LIST` but that also doesn't do what i expect.

I also tried searching for reports and methods, but haven't found anything that seemed to help.

A backup plan would be to get some good parsing tool, so do you know of anything like that.

Anyway, any hints would be helpful and appreciated.

***[EDIT]***
Forgot to mention, the version of my system is 4.6C

Comment: Are you looking for all literals in a program, or just specific hard-coded values?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fairly recent version of ABAP, you can use a regex.

Follow the pattern of this example, but use your source as the text and create your own regex. Have it look for any single quotes on the end of a word separated by spaces or any integers with spaces on either side.  That's just a start, you might need to work on a better pattern.

[String functions count, find, and match](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abenstring_function_find_abexa.htm)

Comment: thank you for the answer, unfortunately my system is pretty ancient... 4.6C and i don't have a regular expression engine. The idea  could have been very good though.